# Quick Truth Table in Logic Problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose We Have:

[image]

How can quickly detect how many "1" are in the truth table of above formula? (without drawing Truth Table).

i think by using some inference. any idea?

we know there are 11 "1"s in TT.

Comment: It depends on how you construct truth tables.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: no it's not depend. just for result of above formula.

Comment: @OpiijasFuchis Please add that clarification to the question.

Comment: You're basically being asked how many valuations yield truth. These are the ones in which $p_4$ is true (there are eight of these instances) plus the ones in which $p_4$ is false and $(p_1\to p_2)\to p_3$ is false. Proceed in this fashion.

Comment: there are 11 "1" in truth table.

Comment: It might come as easier to find how many rows of the truth table are false, and then take 16 less that number.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably one is only interested in $1$s in the *output*.

There are $8$ where $p_4$ is true. Or else we want the antecedent of $p_4$ false, forcing $p_3$ false, and $p_1\longrightarrow p_2$ true. The count of cases where $p_1\longrightarrow p_2$ is true, and the rest false is easy.

One uses a similar analysis in producing a "quick" disjunctive normal form. I  don't know whether this is what problem-setter has in mind.

**Another way:** It can be useful to count instead the ways to make a sentence *false*. In our case we want $p_4$ false and its antecedent true. The antecedent is true if $p_3$ is true ($4$ cases, since then the values of $p_1$ and $p_2$ are arbitrary) or if $p_3$ is false and $p_1\longrightarrow p_2$ is false ($1$ case). That gives a total of $5$. Subtract from $16$.

Comment: Dear Andre, 8 +3 =11? add more detail please.

Comment: Yes, it is $11$. It is clear that you did not need detail!

Comment: you just mentioned 8. please add more detail for 3 remain case.

Comment: There is only $1$ situation in which $p_1\longrightarrow p_2$ is false and the rest false, so there are $3$ where $p_1\longrightarrow p_2$ is true and the rest false.

Comment: Thanks Andre. so nice detail